# Order a directory alphabetically

Tags: php, directory

I have some code that prints out the contents of a directory onto a webpage, what seems to be escaping me is how to make it print out alphabetically.

```
<?php

 $dir="../zpress/pages"; // Directory where files are stored

 if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
 {
 while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false)
 if(!is_dir($filename))
 {
  ?>
  <p><a href="../zpress/pages/<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename;
  ?></a></p>
  <?php
  }
  closedir($dir_list);
  }

  ?>
```

Any suggestion would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
$the_files = array();
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false) {
    if(!is_dir($filename)) {
        array_push($the_files,$filename);
    }
}
sort($the_files);
foreach($the_files as $the_file) { ?>
   <p><a href="../zpress/pages/<?php echo $the_file; ?>"><?php echo $the_file;?></a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it ended up not having anything show up on the page at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scandir` which will returns all files in the directory sorted alphabetically

```
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file) {
   // your code here
}
```

[scandir](http://php.net/scandir)

Comment: `scandir` sorts alphabetically ascending)by default so the `sort` is not needed: http://php.net/scandir

Comment: Great concise answer. Would be better answered if you implemented his case, but in this way it's more didactic as he has to work the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can slurp the entire directory list into memory and then apply `strnatcasecmp` to sort the list:

```
$dir = ".";
$files = glob("$dir/*");
usort($files, 'strnatcasecmp');
// $files is now sorted
```

Using `strnatcasecmp` will give you the order in natural case sort, making for more human-readable output. See here for an explanation: http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/